# Tile view for ListView in WPf

Tags: wpf, listview, wpf-controls

How to simulate a tile view for a `ListView` in WPF?

[image]

I was trying the example shown [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/listview-in-wpf/). But I can't get to the right solution... But I don't want to use that solution as I **it's too much specific**. So how will be the way to accomplilsh that?

**EDIT:** I'm trying this now and seems to work...

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListObservableUsers, ElementName=AdminWindow}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=Picture}"></Image>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Dni}"></Label>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Where the `ElementName=AdminWindow` comes from `<Window .... x:Name="AdminWindow"`

And I created my own `ObservableCollection<MyUser>`

```
    public class MyUser
{
    public MyUser(int id, string dni, Bitmap picture)
    {
        Id = id;
        Dni = dni;
        Image img = new Image();
        FPhiMultipleSources.FromBitmapImage(img, picture);
        Picture = img.Source;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Dni { get; set; }
    public ImageSource Picture { get; set; }
}

... 
public UCAdminMain()
public UCAdminMain()
{
    ListObservableUsers = new ObservableCollection<MyUser>();

    InitializeComponent();
    uiCurrent = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    // Create users to add with its image
    ....
    ListObservableUsers.Add(...);
}
```

And now I'm trying to put them inside a wrap panel. With no luck right now... Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

```
 <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

try to use a wrappanel

Answer (score 2):

An ItemsControl with a WrapPanel as the ItemsContainer would probably be a good fit for what you are trying to do.